# What is the chord progression Gbm - E - Dbm - D called?

Tags: chord-progressions, terminology

The roman numeral form doesn't seem to yeild any results when I search it up. Is this representation correct: i - VII - v - VI
Are there any popular songs that use this chord progression?
I got this chord progression from the second part of Ekcle - Pearl Jigsaw.

Comment: Are there *any* chord progressions that have specific names?

Answer (score 4):

Your assessment of the harmony is correct. The enharmonic spelling of the chords is not. The chords should be named F#m-E-C#m-D in the key of F# minor. This will give you i VII v VI. Theoretically the key of Gb minor would have 9 flats and if you were in Gb minor the E chord would be Fb and the D chord would be Ebb. That would give you Gbm-Fb-Dbm-Ebb. F#m is only 3 sharps. No brainer, right?

I can’t think of any other songs that use this specific chord progression but I wouldn’t be surprised if there are some.